# Adding cities and roads to Google Earth satellite connection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth, url

I've setup an XYZ connection with Google Earth satellite link, but I can't see cities, towns, or roads in QGIS. How to show them?

Comment: I suppose you're talking about the additional layers GE provides when using Ge itself?

Comment: I want to show cities on GE satellite view I've now on QGIS. Is there additional layers for this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean but Google offers various `XYZ` tile services with different themes.

This URL is for the hybrid theme (roads and place names overlaid on imagery):

```
https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

Or this for roads and place names only (transparent background):

```
https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

Comment: Thanks, This was really helpful :)